# ASPOSE.CELLS : Why does a simple Workbook.Save throw a Null Reference Exception?

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

I'm using Aspose.Cells DLLs Version 7.0.0.0 on 64-Bit Windows 7 with .NET 4.0 on my machine. It **does work** on my friends machine, which is running 32-bit windows 7 also with .NET 4.0 - I suspect difference in windows version (x64/x86) could be a problem.

```
using Aspose.Cells;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace BSF.IntegrationTests.Services.FieldConverters
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Useless
    {
        [Test]
        public void VerySimpleTest()
        {
            new Workbook().Save(@"C:\NewFile.xls");
        }
    }
}
```

Aspose.Cells is not open source AFAIK, and there is no way for me to look at the Save source code and come up with some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose.Cells for .NET works fine on 32-bit and 64-bit systems. You may check the topic '[Using Aspose.Cells for .NET on 32-bit and 64-bit systems](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Using+Aspose.Cells+component+on+32+bit+and+64+bit+Platforms)'. Just make sure that you're using .NET 2.0 version of the DLL included in the package. You may also try the latest version of the component. If you still find the same issue then you may report it to [Aspose.Cells support team](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx).

Comment: I did the last and they patched it - It was an issue while accessing Font files. The workaround was `CellsHelper.FontDir = C:\Windows\Fonts` before saving. The issue is here : http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/346480/346480/showthread.aspx raised by my colleague.